# Fancybox open twice programmatically 2.06

Tags: fancybox

I am trying to open fancybox programmatically. Not through link. Once user click addform and i create form manually and show the form in fancybox. sout variable contains the form html.
`$.fancybox({
                            openEffect  : "none",
                            closeEffect : "none",
                            autoDimensions    : false,
                            width             : 620,
                            height            : "auto",
                            content : sOut
                        });`

Then call this
`$.fancybox.close();`

My problem now is when i clcked same button the fancybox not showing up again. if you have done this let me know. How to close properly fancybox so i can reopen.

Comment: it seems like the first event triggers a js error so fancybox won't work the second time ... but this is just a guess. I could help you better with a link.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you must remove the below command in fancybox code:

```
'hideOnContentClick': true
```